# What is the name of "Fn" key for Awesome wm?

Tags: window-managers, awesome-wm

For example:

`awful.key({"Shift", }, "Left", volwidget.down)`

How to find out what to write instead of "Shift" to use "Fn" key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the solution: the program `xev`.
If it runs, it doesn't show a <kbd>Fn</kbd> code. Actually it doesn't have to: X can't see that key.

Anyhow, it shows you the codes for "hot" keys, like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> (for volume down). In my case the name for that is <kbd>XF86AudioLowerVolume</kbd> and I can use it as such in configuration files.

Comment: This solution was offered by Trilby.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142272

Answer (score 10):

you can use `xmodmap -pke` to show the keycode,
then you will get something like this :

> ...
>   keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
>   keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
>   keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
>   keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
>   keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
>   keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
>   keycode 127 = Pause Break Pause Break
>   keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
>   keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
>   ...

You can see that the keycode of `XF86AudioLowerVolume` is `122`,
so you can write your code like this :

> awful.key({ }, "#122", volwidget.down)

Comment: I was searching for how to configure Win + F3 shortcut. Turns out the code is just `F3`. The output of the `xmodmap -pke` command did help to make it clear. I used the name on the right side of the equation though. Of course without the `#`. Still good to know. Still counts...

Answer (score 0):

I use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in both Awesome & Openbox WM's.
In Openbox there is the concept of keychains and it works flawlessly.
Press and release the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key followed by some other key and the action associated with the second key is executed.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in Openbox and in Awesome is `XF86WakeUp` on my Thinkpads. It may be different on your machine.

`xmodmap -pke | grep XF86WakeUp`
gives output
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp

In Awesome the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key also works with the following example code

```
-- open edit ".vimrc"

awful.key({ "XF86WakeUp" }, "v", function ()

awful.util.spawn("termite -e 'nvim /home/.vimrc'") end,

{description = "Edit .vimrc", group = "Code"}),
```

But in Awesome it does not release the `v` key after it is pressed.
So every subsequent press of the `v` key causes vim to open.

What this shows is that the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key can be used in Awesome WM.

I just don't know how to get it to release the second key pressed!